# Is Compound statement always a proposition?

Tags: logic, terminology

"Compound statements are statements using two or more logic operations. Creating a truth table is a systematic way of determining when a compound statement is true and when it is false. "

I read those lines somewhere. Were those correct? If these are correct , Can you please let me know whether compound statement is considered as statement or not. Because as far as the definition of statement or proposition is concerned , statement is always associated with a unique truth value. But compound statement's truth value may vary.  So compound statement is not necessarily a statement.

E.g - If $x^2 - y^2 = 0 $ then $x = y$.

It will be true when $2,2$ but false when $2, -2$.so the truth value is varying.

Can you please correct me if I am wrong anywhere?

Comment: I really can not understand. Can you please elaborate. I have given one  new example. Can you please explain why that compound statement is a statement?

Comment: The definition you quote say "Compound statements are **statements** ..."

Comment: Sorry... but you have changed your example :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is.

The quoted sentence means that the truth value of the *compound* statement is uniquely determined by the truth values of the composing statements through the truth table for the connectives.

Consider the example:

> "If it rains, then the meeting will be postponed".

If "It rains" is *true* and "The meeting will be postponed" is *false*, then the compound statement is *false*.

If we consider an *open* formula, like e.g. $x=2$, it is **not** a statement, because it lacks a definite truth value.

Its truth value will be determined by the value assigned to the variable $x$: if we assign to $x$ the value $2$, the resulting statement is *true*. If we assign to $x$ the value $1$, the statement is *false*.

Comment: can u please explain that example? It seems more complicated. I am still having hard time to see that example as a statement. @Mauro ALLEGRANZA